# C program NOT segfaulting

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make my program segfault deliberately but for some reason it is not and I am kind of scared thinking that maybe something might be wrong with configurations.

These are the programs I ran:

```
int main() {
  char* abc;
  abc[0] = '3';
  return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main() {
  int try[] = {3,4,2};
  printf("%d", try[10]); // this prints '0'
  return 0;
}
```

Could someone please explain why they are not segfaulting? For context, the OS that I am running on is macOS Catalina.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: Accessing invalid memory is Undefined Behaviour. UB does not mean seg fault. Program may segfault, may give wrong values, may even appear to "work" or may produce any other behaviour.

Comment: Try `char* abc = NULL;`. Then it will most likely segfault.

Comment: even for that it does not segfault.

Answer (score 4):

[Segmentation faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) are instances of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB). Read more about C, in particular the C11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) and the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book.

Regarding UB, read [*What every C programmer should know about undefined behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

What is probably happening is that your [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) or [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) happens on *existing* [pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)) of your [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). Read about [page faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) and [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). Read a good [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

You cannot be guaranteed that segmentation faults always happen or can be detected early. Because of  [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), [compiler optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler), and [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem). Even the same [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) could segfault on one run, and not on the next one.

Consider using [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) or some [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

Replace `try[10]` with `try[123456]` (or `abc[0]` with `abc[-456789]` ....) and you *might* observe a different behavior of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). Look also into the generated assembler code (e.g. obtained with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fverbose-asm -S` if using a recent and genuine [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler; recent Clang [accepts](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html) similar options, so you might try compiling with  `clang  -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fverbose-asm -S` the *same* C source files).

If you have access to it, study the source code of the [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) of your system.

Consider using static source code analysis tools such as [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/), or the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). You could be interested in reading [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report explaining some surprizing GCC optimizations.

You could install some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on your laptop and take advantage of the fact that most software inside it are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) so study their source code. See also [linuxfromscratch.org](https://linuxfromscratch.org/)

*Some* source code of [MacOSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) is also open source (but not the GUI).